# How to get rid of gradient and use individual colors in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My issue is that the variable that I am grouping by and assigning to `color` is a continuous variable (numbers from 1:10), so the color will be a gradient. But I need each group to be a different color and not a gradient. How would I achieve this? Code and result below. The Date variable is below also.

```
library(ggplot2)
Date <- 
c("12/31/2021", "12/31/2022", "12/31/2023", "12/31/2024", "12/31/2025", 
  "12/31/2026", "12/31/2027", "12/31/2028", "12/31/2029", "12/31/2030", 
  "12/31/2031", "12/31/2032")

a <- data.frame(id = rep(c(1,2,3),4), date = Date, income = rnorm(12, 60000, 15000))
a$date <- as.Date(a$date,"%m/%d/%Y")

ggplot(a,aes(x = date,y = income,group = id, color = id)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: What's `d`? If we should be working with the dates, can you post them as characters we can paste into a script? As for the gradient, it's because the id is numeric, so `ggplot` assumes it's on a continuous scale. You can set it as a character or factor to make clear that it's discrete

Comment: Like @camille says, just do `color = as.factor(id)`. I have tested it.

Comment: **Important:** I have edited the question changing `date = d$V1[1:12]` to `date = Date`.

Comment: maybe post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: btw, this is why it is good to save group IDs as characters... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can use `as.factor` in the color argument.

To define the colors used you can use `scale_colour_manual` and either assign colors yourself or use the `colorRampPalette` function.

```
ggplot(a,aes(x = date,y = income,group = id, color = as.factor(id))) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5)

ggplot(a,aes(x = date,y = income,group = id, color = as.factor(id))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("green","red","blue")) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5)

gs.pal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"))

ggplot(a,aes(x = date,y = income,group = id, color = as.factor(id))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=gs.pal(length(unique(a$id)))) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5)
```